# Export OLE object (image) from accdb file to folder

Tags: vba, ms-access, ole, ms-access-2016

I've tried using this method to export an ole object (image) but it keeps saying run-time error 438 object doesn't support this property or method on this line:

```
OLEobj.SaveAs "Test" & Me.ID.Value & ".jpg"
```

Original Code:

```
Private Sub CmdExport_Click()
Set OLEobj = Me.OLEField
OLEobj.SaveAs "Test" & Me.ID.Value & ".jpg"
Set OLEobj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: If you do something like MsgBox TypeName(OLEObj), what is the type that is displayed? Does that type support the SaveAs method? Or, is it just some binary field that has the bits for a JPEG and just needs to be written to disk?

Comment: Review https://lebans.com/oletodisk.htm

Comment: @June7 I've tried using the leban tool but it doesn't work for Access 2016.